# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromWei' of undefined, working good in one tab and failing in another tab

Tags: web3js, dapps, dapp-development, web3js-v1.x

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to convert Wei to Ether using the code **window.web3.utils.fromWei("200000",'ether')**. This error shows only on the single page and when I console.log in the same window it shows the same error. But when I'm console.log in other windows it is working fine. Please find below screenshots for both.[image: error Image]

[image: success image]

Comment: How do you load web3.js in your page?

Comment: if (window.ethereum){
window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
window.ethereum.enable();
} else if (window.web3) {
 window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
}

I have used the above code to load Web3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what code you have for your "other windows", but the error:

```
Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

Tells you that in the expression `obj1.obj2.x`, the value of `obj1.obj2` is `undefined`.

This is general to Javascript, and it has nothing to do specifically with Ethereum.

In your case, it means that `window.web3.utils === undefined`.

So your first debug-step should be `console.log(JSON.stringify(window.web3, null, 4))`...

Comment: Thanks, @goodvibration. it helped to solve the error. Actually, In my code, I have loaded elements before loading Web3. I have loaded web3 before loading the page and it resolves my error.